# PM2 couldn't start keystone

Tags: keystonejs

I cant start keystone on pm2. pm2 could not read "COOKIE_SECRET" from .env file.
I did set an environment variable in pm2 config file but I got the error again.
what shall I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you can check is the NODE_ENV variable setup as development or production, or the --env command line that you are using. Reference:

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/

Kindly provide the error message encountered so that there are more information.

Usually one can use "pm2 start keystone.js" to start keystone without problem.